# почему сохранение работает только 1 раз а при повторном столкновении не работает

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui, ubuntu-unity

```
 public int numlev;
public GameObject menu;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        numlev += 1;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("InLevel",numlev);
        menu.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Без полного кода ничего не понятно.

Возможно у тебя переменная num ограниченна до определенного значения и не сбрасывается, либо столкновение не работает (из за неправильных тегов, либо отсутствия коллайдеров), возможно ты вообще не получаешь данные из `PlayerPrefs.GetInt();`

Comment: также дополняю что у меня 2 сцены где используется этот скрипт 2 раза если запущу любую из них то он сохранит а если еще одну любую то не сохранит все смотрю в реестре

Comment: @kirayoshikage Проверь дебагом, есть ли вообще коллизия между объектами. Возможно её нету, вот и не сохраняет.

Comment: вся функция столкновенния работает кроме сохранения

Comment: @kirayoshikage Проверь не в реестре, а в самой игре. У тебя при смене сцены, `int numlev` будет сбрасываться до `0` (дефолт, либо как установленное значение в инспекторе), т.к. он не принимает значений.  В старте пропиши `int numlev = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("InLevel")`

Comment: спасибо, но тоже  не помогло

Comment: @kirayoshikage хм, у тебя на объектах в сценах один и тот же скрипт и компоненты? Может в другой сцене не выставил тег "Player" на объекте или компонентам Collider и IsTrigger = true не поставил с Rigidbody, если это не префаб.  Я вроде попробовал и у меня все сохраняется. :/

Comment: щяс попробую новую версию unity установить посмотрю что изменится

Comment: обновил unity до последней версии и с  пмощью вашей помощи все заработало спасибо)